# Why socket file transferring is slower than windows copy?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcpclient

I have a problem about network file transferring.
Socket TCP/UDP uploading is slower than native windows copy when there are more than 1 clients.

I have some PC with 1Gbps network.

Here are the Windows copy cases.

One client copy from the server, the maximum upload speed is about 100mbps. (It should be higher than 100mbps, there is bottleneck in the route.)

Two clients copy from the server, the maximum upload speed is about 200mbps.

Three clients copy from the server, the maximum upload speed is about 300mbps.

Here are the Socket cases.

One client download from the server, the maximum upload speed is about 100mbps.

Two clients download from the server, the maximum upload speed is about 100mbps.

Three clients download from the server, the maximum upload speed is about 100mbps.

As you see, the socket server upload speed does not increase while the client number increases.

We made a simple program to test this issues. It encounters the same issues.
It's just very simple send and recv calling.
Please check the codes.

```
 class Program
 {
   static List<TcpClient> sessions = new List<TcpClient>();

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      bool isServer = false;
      Console.WriteLine("Run as a server? (Y/N)");
      string answer = Console.ReadLine();
      if (answer.ToUpper().StartsWith("Y")) isServer = true;

      if (isServer)
      {
         TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 13579);
         Console.WriteLine("Listening at: " + ((IPEndPoint)listener.LocalEndpoint).ToString());
         listener.Start();
         Thread workerThread = new Thread(() => 
         {
           while (true)
           {
              lock (sessions)
              {
                 foreach (var client in sessions)
                 {
                   if (client.Available > 0)
                   {
                      byte[] buffer = new byte[client.Available];
                      int length = client.Client.Receive(buffer);
                      string filePath = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);

                      if (File.Exists(filePath))
                      {
                         foreach (var receiver in sessions)
                            receiver.Client.SendFile(filePath, null, null, TransmitFileOptions.UseKernelApc | TransmitFileOptions.WriteBehind);
                      }
                   }
                 }
              } 
              Thread.Sleep(200);
           }

         });

         workerThread.IsBackground = true;
         workerThread.Start();

         while (true)
         {
             TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
             lock (sessions)
             {
                sessions.Add(client);
             }
         }
      }
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Enter the server IP:");
         string ipAddress = Console.ReadLine();
         TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ipAddress, 13579);
         Console.WriteLine("Enter the file path on remote server:");
         string remoteFilePath = Console.ReadLine();
         if(remoteFilePath != "")
                   client.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(remoteFilePath));
         byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[32768];
         while(true)
         {
           try
           {
                    client.Client.Receive(recvBuffer, 32768, SocketFlags.None);
           }
           catch (SocketException e)
           {
                    Console.WriteLine("Transfer interrupted: {0}", e.Message);
                    break;
           }
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

This is blocking us to implement the socket tool with better performance.
Hope stackoverflow guys could help us out.
Thanks advanced.

Comment: Depends on your client/server implementation which we know nothing of. Hence the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: thanks for fast reply, codes attached.

Comment: Are you running the code on the same machines as in the case of testing with windows copy ?

Comment: Yes, the same machines, the same pc as the server.

Comment: I doubt that your code even works correctly, so there isn't much point in measuring it yet. You are (a) assuming you get exactly and only a complete filename in the first read, which isn't valid, and (b) ignoring the result of all the other reads, which also isn't valid. You are also transferring to all the clients sequentially, where the Windows utility can do them in parallel.

Comment: Since it's a tester, we haven't gone detail to implement the validation codes. But we do monitor the Window Task Manger Network dialog and check the files that received. Client.SendFile() is returned directly without waiting for the transferring. We we see clients receiving at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's slower. you are using the same thread to poll all clients.

You should switch to the asynchronous methods in the server (`BeginRead`/`EndRead`)

Comment: In the real project, it is multithread. And i think Client.SendFile() is implemented as mutithread already.

Comment: Actually the AcceptAsync/ReadAsync/WriteAsync are even better, they have less overhead by reusing the state objects and don't throw as many exceptions in standard situations.

Comment: @OliverWho He commented on the code you posted. If you have some other code you want reviewed, post that.

Comment: @Zarat: yes, they are faster since they are designed after the IOCP model that windows uses. But imho the Begin/End methods are easier to use which feels more important for someone that codes like the OP.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is faster if it's implemented with multi-thread. Multithread UDP sendig is even faster than multithread tcp sending. Thank you.

Comment: Note that UDP do not guarantee delivery. Packets can be dropped at any time causing corrupt files. Either handle it yourself (resend packages) or stick with TCP.